# Getting data from crystal report parameter field

Tags: crystal-reports

Greetings.

I have a parameter field in my crystal report called `job`. When i'm calling this report from web page, it prompts me for an input value ("Job1" or "Job2"). After i choose one, it displays in report. But when i try to export report to MS Word with

```
crystalReport.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.WordForWindows, "C:\\foo.doc");
```

i'm getting **"Parameter value is missing"** exception.

If i'm setting value manually with

```
crystalReport.SetParameterValue("job", value);
```

everything works fine, but i don't need to set a value manually. I want to use a value, chosen in crystal report prompt.

How can this be done?

Comment: how does the parameter relate to the export?  i'm not seeing the connection.

Comment: Thanks for comment. There is no relation between this parameter and export. This parameter is used to populate one text field in a report, and it's data is taken from a dropdown list control on a web page. Apparently it's not an issue with a report itself, but with a web page, that cause a postback when export is called. I guess, that a value, chosen from a dropdown list is somehow lost during postback, and that cause a described error.

Comment: as i recall, one needs to explicitly set a dropdownlist control's selected value in a postback.  in any case, is the control's postback triggering the export?

Comment: Export is triggered with a separate button's event handler. I got export working after setting a default value, that is passed to report in any case, even if no value is selected in a dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a webform or a winform?

If you are using a webform make sure that you initialize ,load, set parameter of the reports on each postback.

```
private void ShowReport_click()
{
   ..do initializing,loading,provide logoninfo for data access, provide parameters 
  ... show report
}

private void buttonExport_click()
{
ShowReport_click();
...Your Export Logic goes here
}
```

same can be applied to winforms too.